# Trigger MySQL - Erro sintaxe

Tags: mysql

Alguém saberia me dizer onde estou errando no *Trigger* abaixo?

```
CREATE TRIGGER atualiza_produto 
AFTER INSERT 
ON item_venda FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE produto SET vendido = 's' WHERE id = NEW.id_produto;
END
```

A mensagem de erro:

> ```
> Você tem um erro de sintaxe no seu SQL próximo a '' na linha 5
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O `MySql` tem o `;` como fim de cada `query`, nesse caso ele está tentando executar duas `querys` ao invés de uma, justamente porque o `;` está separando.

Para evitar que isso aconteça, é necessário mostra pra o `MySql` o que o `;` não está finalizando a `query` e sim faz parte do contexto, para isso existe o `DELIMITER`, no seu caso ficaria assim:

```
DELIMITER $$
    CREATE TRIGGER atualiza_produto AFTER INSERT ON item_venda FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        UPDATE produto SET vendido = 's' WHERE id = NEW.id_produto;
    END
$$
```

Tudo o que estiver entre `DELIMITER $$` e `$$` deverá ser executado em conjunto e não separando as `querys` a cada `;`.

Veja mais [aqui](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-defining.html.).

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou! Mais uma coisa: você saberia como desligar as Constraints? Preciso dar Truncate do meu banco todo antes de subir pra produção mas aparentemente o set_checked_constraints = 0 nao funciona no mysql 5